# How to display gridLines in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, gridlines

For some reason my grid lines are not showing when I open the gridview in IE or Chrome. I set the gridLines property to Both already.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" BorderColor="Black" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="350px" ShowFooter="True" AllowSorting="True" BackColor="Black" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="3" GridLines ="Both">


        <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />


        <HeaderStyle Font-Size="7pt" Width="400px" BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" >
        </HeaderStyle>


        <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />


    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grid lines are not displaying in grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321742/grid-lines-are-not-displaying-in-grid-view)

Answer (score 4):

Setting `GridLines` renders the table with the `rules` attribute, which is the old way of doing things and no longer supported. You want to use css for styling things now. This is equivalent to your sample:

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .GridView1 { border-spacing: 3px; border-collapse: separate; }
    .GridView1 > tbody > tr > th, 
    .GridView1 > tbody > tr > td { border: 2px ridge black; padding: 3px; }
  </style>

  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowFooter="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    Height="350px" BackColor="Black" 
    CssClass="GridView1" GridLines="none" CellPadding="-1" CellSpacing="-1">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
    <HeaderStyle Font-Size="7pt" Width="400px" BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF"></HeaderStyle>
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
  </asp:GridView>
```

`GridLines="none"` eliminates the `rules` attribute. Setting the css `border` property defines how your borders look.

Setting `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` to `-1` eliminates the old-style table attributes.

Padding is defined on the `th` and `td` elements with the standard `padding` property.

Spacing is done with the combination `border-spacing` and `border-collapse: separate` properties on the table proper. This is kind of unusual btw- most people go with `border-collapse: collapse` and no border spacing.

The `ridge` border style seems to be not well supported. IE and FF do it but differently. Chome just draws it solid.

You can move some of the other attributes to the stylesheet as well by defining css class for things like `RowStyle` and setting the appropriate properties.

Answer (score 0):

That is weird but you can try something like this 
set a CssClass for your grid

say

> CssClass="grid"

and add a style to it

```
 <style type="text/css"> 
       table.grid{ 
           border-collapse:collapse; 
           border:solid 2px black; 
        } 
        table.grid td, th{ 
           border:solid 2px black; 
        } 
    </style>
```