# How to make GridLines visible in gridView asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

how to make GridLines visible in gridView asp.net?

My source code

```
 <td class="auto-style20" colspan="3">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewAddBus" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" gridLines="Both" cellPadding="4" BorderWidth="1" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#666666">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCatID" HeaderText="Sub category ID">
        <ItemStyle Width="15%" />
        </asp:BoundField>
```

My design still doesn't show gridLines, it only shows outer line and cellPadding doesn't seem to be working... Thanks in advance~
[image]

CSS file for table but they are all comments
[image]

Comment: is this really what your aspx code looks like.. ?? did you forget the matching closing tags..?

Comment: No, I didn't forget the matching close tag, just posted what is useful for people to answer..... What should I do?

Comment: The GridView is rendered as a table tag. Do you have any other CSS that might interfere with the looks?

Comment: Hi Gregory, I've added a new photo and my gridView is set as .auto-style20 { } which has nothing in it. My question is inline style should override CSS or external style sheet? I'm not even sure if I've called them right but I hope you know what I'm trying to say here.

Comment: What does `auto-style20` class has? Remove it and check.

Comment: Check the spelling of GridLines property: should be like specified in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.gridlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grid lines are not displaying in grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321742/grid-lines-are-not-displaying-in-grid-view)