# Why am I not seeing grid lines on my gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridlines

I have a gridview on my web page. 
I am able to populate the Grid using C# in the behind code.
Here is a sample screen of 2 columns and 2 rows:
[image]

What I don't understand is why there Gridlines are not showing on the rows of data when I have it set on the gridview properties to show "both".

```
<asp:GridView id="gvappts" 
              runat="server" 
              AllowPaging="True"        
              AllowSorting="True" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              BorderColor="#EFE6F7"
              ForeColor="#003399" 
              Width="100%" 
              Font-Size="Small" 
              GridLines="Both"
              BorderStyle="Solid" 
              BorderWidth="1px" 
              CellPadding="3">

<Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="apptid" HeaderText="Appt #" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are your gridlines white?

Comment: No, I don't believe so. And I checked my CSS nothing about borders is white.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the BorderColor?

Comment: Try to remove the gridlines property (Set it to none not literally remove it :P) And then add a border to `<td>` in css

Comment: Are you using some kind of bootstrapper that could be overriding the `td` style. Since `th` does display correctly would seem to indicate that something is interferring. What GridLines=Both does is set `border="1"` in HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grid lines are not displaying in grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321742/grid-lines-are-not-displaying-in-grid-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the comments on this post are correct to some extent which is, you mention that the issue must rely in the styles, after going line by line in my style sheets I found the culprit style and was able to get the grid-lines to show.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code to your row border..

```
<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#0000CC" 
                            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px"/>
```

And also try the same to columns.